# SQL Server : Display Employees Having Max & Min Salary Department Wise?(Check Screenshot) Any Better Solutions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, inner-join

**Below is my Solution..Any Better Approach Please Suggest**
**Below Solution generated from HR Database in SQL Server Migrated from Oracle Database**

This is Output
[image: Screenshot]

This is Table Structure
[image: Table Structure]

```
SELECT e.DEPARTMENT_ID,d.MaxSalary,es.FIRST_NAME,dm.MinSalary,esd.FIRST_NAME
FROM 
    EMPLOYEES e
    JOIN (  SELECT department_id, MAX(salary) MaxSalary 
            FROM EMPLOYEES 
            GROUP BY DEPARTMENT_ID) d
    ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID=d.DEPARTMENT_ID
    JOIN (  SELECT first_name,DEPARTMENT_ID 
            FROM EMPLOYEES ess 
            WHERE SALARY IN (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=ess.DEPARTMENT_ID)) es
    ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID=es.DEPARTMENT_ID
    JOIN (  SELECT department_id,min(salary) MinSalary 
            FROM EMPLOYEES group by DEPARTMENT_ID) dm
    ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID=dm.DEPARTMENT_ID
    JOIN (  SELECT first_name,DEPARTMENT_ID
            FROM EMPLOYEES ess 
            WHERE SALARY in (SELECT MIN(salary) FROM EMPLOYEES WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID=ess.DEPARTMENT_ID )) esd
    ON e.DEPARTMENT_ID=esd.DEPARTMENT_ID
GROUP BY 
    e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    ,d.MaxSalary
    ,es.FIRST_NAME
    ,dm.MinSalary
    ,esd.FIRST_NAME
```

Comment: Why do you have `MaxSalary` and `MinSalary` column? what is your expected output?

Comment: From Above : In Department 2 Michael is getting Max Salary & Pat is getting Min Salary .To display the employees details having minsalary department wise & max salary department wise in a single output.

Comment: ok so images shows your query's output result. It would be better to share your table structure.

Comment: table structure added to question

Answer (score 2):

Your query looks quite complicated, I'm not an SQL specialist and I'm sure someone with more knowledge will improve on this but here's my working (The following code has not been syntax/error checked and probably should only be used as a guideline):

Firstly I'd simplify your query to only include the `MIN` and `MAX` salaries for each department in a single query:

```
SELECT
    [DEPARTMENT_ID] = e.DEPARTMENT_ID
    ,[MaxSalary] = MAX(e.salary)
    ,[MinSalary] = MAX(e.salary)
FROM
    EMPLOYEES e
GROUP BY
    e.DEPARTMENT_ID
```

At this point you'll have results such as:

```
DEPARTMENT_ID    MaxSalary    MinSalary
10               4400         4400
20               13000        6000
30               11000        2500
...              ...          ...
```

From here you could either use a sub-query as you have previously (though I believe this is often inefficient):

```
SELECT
    aggr.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
    , [FIRST_NAME] = maxEmp.[FIRST_NAME]
    , aggr.[MaxSalary]
    , [FIRST_NAME] = minEmp.[FIRST_NAME]
    , aggr.[MinSalary]
FROM
    (   SELECT
            [DEPARTMENT_ID] = e.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
            ,[MaxSalary] = MAX(e.[salary])
            ,[MinSalary] = MAX(e.[salary])
        FROM
            EMPLOYEES e
        GROUP BY
            e.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
    ) aggr
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES maxEmp ON maxEmp.[salary] = aggr.[MaxSalary] AND maxEmp.[DEPARTMENT_ID] = aggr.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES minEmp ON minEmp.[salary] = aggr.[MinSalary] AND minEmp.[DEPARTMENT_ID] = aggr.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
```

Alternatively you could use [`HAVING`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx) as follows:

```
SELECT
    [DEPARTMENT_ID] = e.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
    , [FIRST_NAME] = maxEmp.[FIRST_NAME]
    , [MaxSalary] = MAX(e.[salary])
    , [FIRST_NAME] = minEmp.[FIRST_NAME]
    , [MinSalary] = MAX(e.[salary])
FROM
    EMPLOYEES e
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES maxEmp ON maxEmp.[DEPARTMENT_ID] = e.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
    INNER JOIN EMPLOYEES minEmp ON minEmp.[DEPARTMENT_ID] = e.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
GROUP BY
    e.[DEPARTMENT_ID]
    , maxEmp.[salary]
    , maxEmp.[FIRST_NAME]
    , maxEmp.[salary]
    , minEmp.[FIRST_NAME]
HAVING
    maxEmp.[salary] = MAX(e.[salary])
    AND maxEmp.[salary] = MIN(e.[salary])
```

I'm not convinced either is a perfect solution, however it's something to work from. I'd recommend creating an [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) with your structure and some dummy data to enable people to help you with more ease. As with your results it will return multiple rows should there be multiple employees with the minimum or maximum salaries.

Answer (score 0):

You can use two approaches

1. using dense_rank() with join

select a.department,a.max_sal_emp, a.max_salary,b.min_sal_emp,b.min_salary from

(select department,first_name as max_sal_emp,salary as max_salary from (select department,first_name,salary,dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary desc) as max_sal_rank from employees)e where max_sal_rank=1) a

join

(select department,first_name as min_sal_emp,salary as min_salary from (select department,first_name,salary,dense_rank() over (partition by department order by salary) as min_sal_rank from employees)e where min_sal_rank=1) b

on a.department=b.department order by department;

2. Using correlated subquery

   select department_id,first_name,salary from
   (select department_id,first_name,salary,(select max(salary) as max_dept_sal from employees e2 where e2.department_id = e1.department_id),select min(salary) min_Dept_Sal from employees e2 where e2.department_id = e1.department_id) from employees e1) e
   where salary = max_dept_sal or salary = min_dept_sal
   order by department_id, salary desc

> ```
> Expected O/p format:
> dept_id first_name salary
> 1        aaa         10000
> 1        abc         2000
> 2        xxx         75000
> 2        xyz         32000
> ```